# How to access Django database with JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, database

I have developed a website for an interactive game (mafia) using Django (python), but then i realized i need the displaying data(such as list of alive players, player messages, list of voted for lynch players, etc.) to be real-time and update instantly, whereas my website needs to be refreshed in order to see the updated database content.

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv00J.jpg)

After realizing that, I started learning JavaScript, but now that I'm almost done, I noticed that Django and JavaScript functions cannot be called interactively, meaning I can't do JS functions and change database attributes at the same time. So I need an interactive frontend that updates data instantly, while being able to access and change database attributes as well(JS doesn't do this apparently). What should I learn for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make views return json values which can be read and used by your javascript code

Comment: Look into Ajax and building an API, which can be accessed with JS. If you're using Django already, Django REST framework is a good tool for building an API.